# How does GWT RPC work? (set of URL)

Tags: java, url, gwt, rpc

i have problems with understanding parts of the RPC mechanism.

[RPC Plumbing diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1CQ3.png)

I don't understand what exactly YourServiceProxy and ServiceDefTarget is doing and which role this class/interface plays.

Somebody told me ServiceDefTarget defines the URL of my service.

But in my project we also have the part "@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")". I thought this is setting the URL?

I'm confused about that and if somebody could give me a short explanation it would be awesome :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceDefTarget defining your service URL is right, but it only defines the main part of the URL, for example http://myService.com/stock.

The part "@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")" is needed to call specific interfaces of your service, which results in http://myService.com/stock/stockPrices

The service proxy emulates the service as if it would be on the client itself. All methods you call from your service, are called on the proxy, which sends these to your service. If your service sends a callback, the proxy will receive it and notify your other classes. In other words, it handles the communication between your client and service.

Comment: Well, this @RemoteServiceRelativePath() seems to be not working as expected, after working correctly my App with "/greet/sayhi", "sayhi" is configured in the remotepath and in the web.xml, I changed to another URL -> /greet/sayHi (in the remorepath and in the web.xml) and the APP communication with the server stops working. Restaring Eclipse and Chrome does not help.